Vue3 Composition API: nested template refs
currently i am rewriting my Vue 3 application to use the Composition API and I have a problem rewriting


methods: {
  isDataValid() {
    if (this.$refs.data.$refs.cost.enabled) {
      return this.$refs.data.$refs.cost.$refs.module.dataValid();
    }
  }
}



From the Vue Official Template Refs Docs I know I have to create a ref and assign it to the corresponding component but I do not understand how to do it in my special case with nested refs. The child components still use the Options API, how can I archive the rewriting for my case?

I would rethink how this is done.  Parent directly accessing data of Child or Grandchild component is not good practice.  A change in the child's code code break the code in the parent, for example.  I think they made this type of coding practice harder to accomplish in Composition API on purpose.  It's better for child components to emit data, or use something like global store, e.g. pinia

I just rewrite the parent component,I think you can rewrite the children follow this.


<child ref="data"/>
...
const data = ref()
function isDataValid(){
if (data.value.$refs.cost.enabled) {
      return data.value.$refs.cost.$refs.module.dataValid();
    }
}



